# How to make lm ignore NA columns

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm

I'm trying to calculate a bunch of betas.  Unfortunately, sometimes some of the columns are all `NA`.  Here's a toy example:

```
x = structure(c(0.946032318625641, -0.472255854964591, -0.570914946839299, -0.624246840976067, -0.484359645048786, 0.888922481497905, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Dim = c(6L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(c("AAPL", "AXP", "BA", "CAT", "CSCO", "CVX"), c("TV", "HG", "PT")))
y = structure(c(0.0519592742218189, 0.0148741387994269, 0.0646644308305699, 0.0406382502886822, 0.0454770268265812, 0.0403287646059043), .Names = c("AAPL", "AXP", "BA", "CAT", "CSCO", "CVX"))
b = lm(y ~ x)$coefficients
```

How can I tell `lm` to ignore those?  I don't mind if some of the betas come back as `NA`.

Comment: `lm( na.action = na.omit )`

Comment: @Sathish Do you mean `b = lm(y ~ x, na.action = na.omit)$coefficients`?  That doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: @lebelinoz yes, but please look at the suggestion by Zheyuan Li. I have not tested it. To get a list of functions for `na.action`, please read `?na.fail`

Comment: @李哲源ZheyuanLi You mean remove whole columns so my `b` has less columns?  That won't really work in the broader context of what I'm trying to do:  my `b = lm` line is in a big for-loop where `x` sometimes has all-NA columns

Comment: @李哲源ZheyuanLi So my inputs don't have the right shape?  Do I need to change my inputs `x` and `y`?

Comment: just a debugging technique. use `method = 'model.frame' ` in `lm` to see the data used to fit the `lm` model.

Comment: @李哲源ZheyuanLi What should I replace it with?  All zeroes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess your main issue is **how to achieve nice alignment**. Looks like you are fitting a number of linear models with a loop. The dimension of the design matrix stays fixed, but different columns may suddenly disappear, i.e., become NA in different iteration. In the end, you want a nice coefficient matrix, with padded NA for those disappearing columns.

A simple solution is to replace those NA columns with zero columns. In this way, the design matrix is rank-deficient, and coefficients for those zero columns will be NA.

Comment: Thanks.  I added the line `for (i in 1:ncol(x)) if (all(is.na(x[, i]) | x[, i] == 0)) x[, i] = 0` right before my `b = ` line and it seems to work.  Note that I'm also zeroing any columns which have a mix of NA's and 0's because those were causing trouble as well.